# How to create alert for low storage on K8sVolumeSample metric in NewRelic

Tags: alert, monitoring, newrelic, nrql

I have issues with creating alert for checking if any of volume attached to pods on kubernetes has low storage. I have found that metric `K8sVolumeSample` have property called `fsUsedPercent` but don't know how to create alert that will notify me with all volumes that have `fsUsedPercent` larger than 80 (which is 80%).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. In NewRelic, I need to write basic query like `FROM K8sVolumeSample SELECT max(fsUsedPercent) FACET podName, pvcName, namespaceName` and then, when creating an alert I can define thresholds for `fsUsedPercent`.